# svg graphic: fixed and scalable

Tags: svg

I draw graphics for my program in corel draw (x6),
after that export it as svg files, and my program
uses this svg files.

Let's say I draw "arrow" in corel draw program.
It consists of tip and line. 
I need to show this "arrow" in my program,
but I need "tip" part to be not scalable,
while "line" should be scalable.

The most simple solution which works, split "arrow"
into two parts, convert "tip" part to bitmap during program starts.

But it requires too much time for complex pictures.

And I wonder, is it possible in svg format to say this part should
not be scaled, and this should? And how this can be exported from corel draw?

I found something suitable in corel draw, to play with scale for diffrent parts of picture,
but during export to svg all my definitions was lost.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no concept of a non-scaling element.  At my last job, I worked with the SVG working group to try to get this feature introduced (nonscaling elements are really useful in engineering drawings), and it is on the roadmap for SVG 2.

The issue is [SVG-ISSUE-2400](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/track/issues/2400).

The way to do this for now, is to implement a zoom event, that dynamically rescales nonscaling elements when the zoom level changes.